# Count Non-Null Values Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, null, pandas-groupby

I have this set of data:

```
UserID  AccountNum
A001      12345
A001       NaN
A001      56789
```

My wish output is like this, I want to count number of AccNum but I don't want to count the null value

```
UserID  TotalAccNum
A001      2
```

I have tried this query:

```
data.groupby('UserID').agg({'AccountNum': ['count']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

If not working, `NAN` are strings, not missing values.

So need:

```
data['AccountNum'] = data['AccountNum'].astype(float)
```

Or:

```
data['AccountNum'] = pd.to_numeric(data['AccountNum'], errors='coerce')
```

And then your solution should be simplify:

```
df = data.groupby('UserID')['AccountNum'].count().reset_index(name='TotalAccNum')
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
df[df['AccountNum'].notnull()].count()
```